# Variable size is more than the memory one GPU has

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I train my model in tensorflow platform, but I meet some problem.I have
a variable which is shaped [6000000, 128], its size is more than 20G, my machine has 6 GPUs each has 11G memory. Can I put one variable on two GPUs? If yes, how to do it.

Comment: I think it depends on what operation  you want perform on that variable. For instance, if it is matrix multiplication you can split the rows of your variable and feed it as regular data in batches to a placeholder.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I now split the tensor into 3 tensors. I can run my program now.

Answer (score 0):

**Multiple GPUs**

The code below allows operations to run on multiple GPUs. We use 3 GPUs to compute 3 separate matrix multiplication. Each multiplication generates a 2x2 matrix. Then we use a CPU to perform an element-wise sum over the matrices.

```python
import tensorflow as tf

c = []
for i, d in enumerate(['/gpu:0', '/gpu:1', '/gpu:2']):
    with tf.device(d):
        a = tf.get_variable(f"a_{i}", [2, 3], initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-1, 1))
        b = tf.get_variable(f"b_{i}", [3, 2], initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-1, 1))
        c.append(tf.matmul(a, b))

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    sum = tf.add_n(c)

sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

print(sess.run(sum))
# [[-0.36499196 -0.07454088]
# [-0.33966339  0.30250686]]
```

You can refer this for more details https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu